# Cannot refresh UI if update in ItemView

Tags: core-data, swiftui

It works fine if I just put the code of ItemView in ForEach, touch the name of list item, attribute check toggled, name color changed. When I extract the code into ItemView, data changed but UI not refreshed, why?

notice that Item is class, not a struct. Maybe it's important.

```
import CoreData
class Item: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var createAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var check: Bool
    ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createAt", ascending: false)]) var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
//                        HStack {
//                            Text("\(item.name!)").foregroundColor(item.check ? .red : .gray)
//                            Spacer()
//                        }.onTapGesture {
//                            item.check.toggle()
//                            try? self.context.save()
//                        }
                        ItemView(item: item)
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        let index = indexSet.first!
                        let item = self.items[index]
                        self.context.delete(item)
                        try? self.context.save()
                    })
                }
                Button(action: {
                    let item = Item(context: self.context)
                    item.id = UUID()
                    item.createAt = Date()
                    item.name = "New Item"
                    try? self.context.save()
                }) {
                    Text("New")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(item.name!)").foregroundColor(item.check ? .red : .gray)
            Spacer()
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.item.check.toggle()
            try? self.context.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `ItemView` is by default detected as equal, because `item` property is pointer.

Here is what could be done (snapshot is not testable), so just scratchy (but it should work by experience):

1) change `ForEach` as follows

```
ForEach(items) { item in
    ItemView(item: item).equatable()
```

2) [!!!] make sure your `Item` is also `Equatable` taking into account changing `check` property

3) make `ItemView` equatable

```
struct ItemView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ItemView, rhs: ItemView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.item == rhs.item // preferable, but can be other appropriate
    }
    ...
```

Update: alternate way

```swift
struct ItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    var item: Item

    @State private var refresh: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(item.name!)").foregroundColor(item.check ? .red : .gray)
                .background(Color.clear.opacity(self.refresh ? 1.0 : 0.0)) // just to be in view body
            Spacer()
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.item.check.toggle()
            try? self.context.save()
            self.refresh.toggle() // force refresh self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lhs and rhs always point to the same address, so always equal.

Comment: @foolbear, that is why items should be explicitly conform to Equatable, override == and compare all properties, because by default only pointers are compared.

Comment: 2 items point to the same address, all properties of these 2 items is the same too, so always equal. It's meaningless.

Comment: @foolbear, that's really strange... anyway, there is always alternate way, see updated part.

Comment: yes, it force the ItemView refresh. but it's no normal way. I found ItemView(item: item).id(item.check) or ItemView(item: item).id(UUID()) work fine, but they are not normal way too, I think.

Comment: @foolbear, using `.id` is just another way to force-refresh, but might be more destructive, because force recreate view completely.

Comment: yes, so I want to find a better solution for this simple user case.